# How to make bottomsheet resize to keep content visible?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a modal `DraggableScrollableSheet` widget that I use to display info. The problem is that although I can set the initial & max size parameters, it doesn't guarantee that the content inside of the sheet is always visible on different devices.

On my pixel 7 I see all of the content perfectly. But, testing on my iPhone shows the bottom sheet with content that is cutoff & out of view. I'm trying to make the bottom sheet dynamically size so all content is visible, while also not giving too much space on the bottom.

Bottom Sheet:

```
await showModalBottomSheet(
    useSafeArea: true,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
        expand: false,
        initialChildSize: 0.75,
        maxChildSize: 0.9,
        builder: (context, scrollController) {
          return ViewPlaceSheet(
              place: widget.place,
              scrollController: scrollController);
    }));
```

I've tried:

- Setting `useSafeArea` to true
- Using a `Wrap`, `Column`, etc. (Gives size errors)
- Using `BoxConstraints` in `showModalBottomSheet` (No change)
- Not setting `initialChildSize` / `maxChildSize`

I was expecting one of these solutions to work. Although, even the janky workarounds like using `Wrap` wasn't giving me the expected result of keeping all content in view.